# Correct way to query Firebase and filter FDataSnapshot

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, firebase

[image: Heres a look into my data]
In my application a user makes  a project, each project has title and posted_by. When a user logs into my application I want to display the titles of the projects they made. Whats the proper way to query this using the Firebase iOS SDK?

I am currently trying to get to https://rocketshiptest.firebaseio.com/projects/$PROJID and grab each project. This is code that I using to do this:

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://rocketshiptest.firebaseio.com/projects"];
[[ref queryOrderedByValue] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSString *projPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://rocketshiptest.firebaseio.com/projects/%@", snapshot.key];
    Firebase *refProj =[[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:projPath];
    [[refProj queryOrderedByValue] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshotProj) {
        NSDictionary *arr = snapshotProj.value;
        //What should I do to filter the NSDictionary? 
    }];
}];
```

But after I grab this data I am unsure what to do. Should I make an NSDictionary and store all of the projects and then use NSPredicate to filter the projects that my current user made? Or is there support in the Firebase SDK to only grab the projects that my current user made?

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase docs suggest denormalize data so that you don't have to download all the data at a location and filter on the client side.

I would suggest having another top level node called users, which as it's keys would have the ids of all the users using the app. For each user, you could store data for that user like name or something, as well as an array of projects that they own. It would look something like this:

[image]

Then, it is simple to get all projects for a certain user:

```
NSString * currentUserId = ... // stored somewhere in app

Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://rocketshiptest.firebaseio.com/users/%@", currentUserId]];

[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeVaue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    NSArray<NSString*> * projectKeys = [snapshot.value[@"projects"] allKeys];

    for(NSString * projectKey in projectKeys)
    {
        Firebase *projectRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://rocketshiptest.firebaseio.com/projects/%@", projectKey]];

        [projectRef observeEventType:FEventTypeVaue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

            //do something with project
        }];

    }
}];
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach and I currently trying to implement this. The only problem I'm having is adding the same childByAutoId to both Projects and Users/UID/projects.